# AWS Lambda (Python) - Downloading file from internet and upload directly to AWS S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to download a file from an API to upload (stream) directly into S3.

My code for local downloads (which works perfectly):

```
import requests
import datetime
import os

headers = {'Authorization': 'apikey THISISHIDDEN'}
baseURL = 'https://api.test.au/busschedule/'
target_path = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d schedule') + '.zip'

response = requests.get(baseURL, stream=True, headers=headers)
handle = open(target_path, "wb")
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
    if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
        handle.write(chunk)
handle.close()
```

My attempt to download and stream to S3 (which didn't work):

```
# import requests
import datetime
import os
import boto3
import botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3 as urllib3

# Get environment variables from serverless.yml
bucket = "bucket"  
s3folder = "schedules"

# Set standard script parameters
headers = {'Authorization': 'apikey THISISHIDDEN'}
baseURL = 'https://api.test.au/busschedule/'


def run(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    datetimestamp = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')
    filename = datetimestamp + " bus schedule.zip"
    key = s3folder + '/' + filename  # your desired s3 path or filename
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    s3.upload_fileobj(http.request('GET', baseURL,
                                   headers=headers, preload_content=False),
                                   bucket, key)


def main():
  run({},{})


if __name__ == "__main__":
        exit(main())
```

The error I get returned by CloudWatch is:

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made.  Timeout after 300.10s.
```

EDIT: The lambda function has a timeout of 300 seconds; but this should be more than long enough to download the file (6mb).  Downloading locally is done within 10 or so seconds.  Does anyone have a better approach to this?

Comment: This error means that this unhandled exception was raised during initialization (when your code is imported). Probably some code tries to get `os.environ['URL']`. Any chance something missing in the code here?
BTW this code is malformatted, you have an invalid string literal

Comment: My apologies, in an attempt to clean up the code for Stack Overflow, I've uploaded the wrong issue.  I am using serverless to deploy the code to AWS Lambda and misnamed the environment variable (URL).

Comment: What is the memory size? Using low memory size will also mean low network bandwith

Comment: 512mb memory allocated for a very small (less than 10mb) file

Comment: I suggest to first run the GET request, then the S3 upload, and add prints to see where the timeout occur.
You can also try with a fetching a smaller file size to see if it's somehow related.

Comment: Couldn't resolve the issue using the above code - swapped to a different library.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue using the 'smart_open' library:

```
response = requests.get(baseURL, stream=True, headers=headers)
s3url = 's3://' + bucket + '/' + key
with smart_open(s3url, 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(response.content)
```

I have another issue to resolve (Lambda permissions) but this will be a separate question.  Running this locally worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of uploading file (even larger than 6MB) using AWS lambda:

Step 1: Create a pre-signed URL based on the get or put request, return this url as the response.
Step 2: Use this URL in your file uploader class on UI.

**Pros**

1. Code is scalable in terms of file size since lambda has limit of 6MB, this logic works with lesser and higher data.
2. Pre-Signed URL is secure way, we can provide the time limit for the url after which the url is expired.

**Cons**

1. Its a 2 step process, so need to hit 2 APIs to upload single file.

Please feel free to give feedback for this approach.